How can I set individual 'Reply-To' Addresses using Amazon SES api V2?
I have set up a emailing system for my company to send mass notifications on specific days, from a no-reply email, for users that still have actions pending on their accounts. This is uses Amazons SES API v2 'sendBulkEmail' service.
This functionality works great, however the I've noticed users will still try to reply to the email to ask question (even though it is clear in the notification email that it's a no reply notification).
My question is, am I able to set up 'Reply-To' addresses to the specific emails sent?
I am aware, as per the documentation, that in my JSON request payload I can set a list of reply to emails, however it seems that this would mean everyone in this list will receive a reply for any one user replying. I would instead like to be able to set the reply to email for each email sent to go to their account manager.
Things I've tried:
Instead of having the reply to array outside the email entries array, I set it up so each email entry would have it's own reply to array
    "BulkEmailEntries": [
        {
            "Destination": {
                "ToAddresses": [
                    "test@example.com"
                ]
            },
            "ReplacementEmailContent": {
                "ReplacementTemplate": {
                    "ReplacementTemplateData": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
                }
            },
            "ReplyToAddresses": ["reply@examply.com"]
        }
    ],

this does successfully send emails, however this still doesn't set the reply to address in the email header and the original sender is still the reply.
Instead I tried using the 'ReplacementHeaders' tag as per the documentation to set the 'Reply-To' that way
    "BulkEmailEntries": [
        {
            "Destination": {
                "ToAddresses": [
                    "test@example.com"
                ]
            },
            "ReplacementEmailContent": {
                "ReplacementTemplate": {
                    "ReplacementTemplateData": "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
                }
            },
            "ReplacementHeaders": [{
                "Name": "Reply-To",
                "Value" "reply@examply.com" 
            }]
        }
    ],

This time I received a 400 response status as it seems SES won't support setting this header.
To make sure the syntax was correct I changed the name from 'Reply-to' to 'X-Reply-To', which sent the email and showed the 'X-Reply-To' header in the email but still didn't reply to the new address
I know SES has the 'sendEmail' service which sends a single email and I could set the reply to address list there and that would work, however the our service is hosted on salesforce which has API limits and this would eat into those limits drastically and could cause scalability issues.
I am aware this may not be possible but thought I'd post here first before giving up.
Thanks in advance to any and all who response, your help is greatly appreciated.

Your first JSON snippet looks correct. Are you sure that it doesn't work? I mean, your no-reply address will still be shown as sender, Reply-To header only makes a difference when you click "reply" in a client supporting this feature (almost all nowadays AFAIC, but still worth checking with another one). E.g. you'll see a message sent by (from) noreply@yourcompany.com, but clicking "reply" will create a draft message to replyto@yourcompany.com

@STerliakov 100%, checked multiple times with different emails and different email clients. The documentation doesn't actually say you can put this parameter here in the JSON, usually its outside the BulkEmailEntries array so every email sent has the same reply to email list which wouldn't work for my use case. I just tried it as a hail Mary attempt.
